# Eclipse maven build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Tags: java, maven, apache-nifi

I just created new maven project as follows:

[image]

[image]

and when I hit Finish, it started giving me following error:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.mycompany:first-custom-nifi-processor:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.nifi:nifi-nar-bundles:pom:0.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM
```

This creates projects like this:

[image]

and with following pom:

**first-custom-nifi-processor/pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-nar-bundles</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>first-custom-nifi-processor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>nifi-custom-nifi-processor-processors</module>
        <module>nifi-custom-nifi-processor-nar</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

What I am missing?

Comment: So does `org.apache.nifi:nifi-nar-bundles:pom:0.1.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT` exist in your Maven repository?

Comment: I have `org\apache\nifi\nifi-nar-bundles\0.1.0-incubating` (without `SNAPSHOT`). Shouldnt it download on itself?

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean whether it is in your local repository, but whether it exists at all in the configured repositories in your `settings.xml`. (If you do not have a `settings.xml` then the question is: Does it exist in MavenCentral?)

Comment: Just checked. Surprisingly I had settings.xml ill configured in eclipse. Somehow local repository was correctly configured and it contained `org\apache\nifi\nifi-nar-bundles\0.1.0-incubating`. So when I deleted `SNAPSHOT` from pom and it started working. But I was guessing if what I did was wrong.

Comment: I cannot really follow you. Your local repository is filled from the remote repositories you have configured in your `settings.xml`. If you have none, MavenCentral is used. So the first thing to check is whether the remote repositories you configured contain the Parent POM you are interested in.